# Error in @property for getter and setter Python 3.9

Tags: python-3.x, abstract-class, abstract-methods

I am learning this abstract topic but long time ago stuck in this excercise, really dont know why not working, thank you people

```
class Square(ForeignClass):

    def __init__(self, height=0, width=0):
        self._height = height
        self._width = width

    @property
    def get_height(self):
        return self._height

    @get_height.setter
    def set_height(self, height_param):
        self._height = height_param

A_obj = Square(90, 90)
print(A_obj.get_height)
A_obj.set_height(777)
print(A_obj.get_height)
```

=================================================

```
output after running

90
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Square.py", line 36, in <module>
    A_obj.set_height(777)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: That's not how `@property.setter` works - the proper invocation is `A_obj.set_height = 777`. If you want to use it with method call syntax, just make it a regular method.

Comment: Note that as written, getters/setters that are only used to access "private" variables are a stupid Java-ism that should never be used in idiomatic Python (or Java for that matter).

Comment: Don't name your methods `get_height` and `set_height` if you're using `@property` syntax. Just name them both `height`. Then you just access `A_obj.height` to invoke the getter and assign with `A_obj.height = 777` to invoke the setter. You could keep the methods as they are and use `height = property(get_height, set_height)` *instead* of using the `@property` decorator syntax.